# Чи існує префікс "по-" і що він означає?

Tags: префікс

Шукаю префікс для утворення потрібного мені терміну, здалось, що *по-* міг би підійти, але чи він існує, і що він означає?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Занадто неточний запит: змушує використовувати майже усі догадки чи уникати розвитку відповіді.*

Приросток [*по*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0), з урахуванням [розділки](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%84%D1%96%D1%81)

**Дієслово**

- Префікси зі значенням повторюваності дії — **по**-: ***по**стукувати, **по**трушувати*.
- Словозмінні префікси для утворення форми доконаного виду — **по**-: *шити → **по**шити*.

**Прислівник**

- Прислівникові [продуктивні] префікси для утворення прислівників від прикметників та числівників — **по-**: ***по-**батьківському, **по-**батьківськи, **по-**перше*.

**Іменник**
*Джерело не представляє такого, але, гадаю, просто пропустили*

- Дієслівні префікси в віддієслівних іменниках — **по**-: ***по**дорожувати → **по**доріж, **по**радити → **по**рада*.